# Custom keyboard on IOS 8 wrecked appearing animation

Tags: ios, animation, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

We are creating a custom keyboard for IOS8 and we found an issue with appearing of the keyboard - the animation of appearing is very cutted, longlasting and not smooth at all, but it disappears normally like a native keyboard. Did somebody have the same issue and were you able to fix that somehow? Or should we wait for updates from Apple?

Comment: How about filing a bug report with Apple?

Comment: Solved? .......